# Как получить характеристический вектор множества?

Tags: c#, множества

У меня есть универсальное множество string[] universal и есть множество А - string[] mna
К примеру универсальное множество состоит из элементов (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), а множество А содержит элементы (1, 2, 4)
В ответе я должен получить множество (1, 1, 0, 1, 0). Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Используйте хешсет.

Comment: А можно точнее, я с хешсетом только подмножества смог сделать

Comment: какой вопрос - такой ответ. Точнее не ответ, а комментарий. Вы же не поясняете, что такое ваш этот вектор и как ваш массив результирующий получился. Как вы можете ожидать, что я вам алгоритм распишу? Вы не пишете ни про размер массивов, ни про интервалы значений в нем, ни про то, уникальные значниия или нет. Вы не описали ничего из своей задачи - соотвественно я вам только могу сказать, что вам скорее всего понадобится хешсет, большего сказать не могу.

Comment: Массив вводится вручную, от 1 до 25 элементов, интервала значений нету, может быть и (1, 100), значения во множествах не повторяются. По вектору инфа с вики вот:
Пусть для простоты  S = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.  Подмножеству  A = {1,2,6,7,9}  соответствует набор 110001101. Такой 0-1 набор называется характеристическим вектором множества  S.

Comment: в каком случае пишется 1, а в каком 0? Значения всегда сортированные? Хранит ли первый массив все значения, что встретятся во втором? Вы мне википедию цитируете, я же тоже вам могу сказать, что есть документация по хешсетам, но вам это также мало поможет, как мне ваша информация. Попробуйте задачу сформулировать яснее. У меня есть предположение, что вам надо и кода там немного, но я бы просто хотел удостовериться, что мое предпложение совпадает с вашими условиями.

Comment: Извиняюсь, что плохо описал задание. Значения отсортированы, второй массив является подмножеством первого, и может хранить либо все его значения, либо некоторый, либо вообще не содержать. Если массив А содержит то же значение, что и универсальное множество, то на месте этого значения должна появиться единица, в противном случае ноль. То есть ->
(1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6) - Это универсальное множество
(1, 2, 4, 5) - Это подмножество А
(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0) - Это характеристический вектор. Единицы это совпадающение значение универсального и подмножества, а нули различия

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смысл решения в том, чтобы проверить вхождение элемента из universal в mna

```
var universal = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var mna = new int[] {1, 4, 7};

var vector = new int[universal.Length];
var set = new HashSet<int>(mna);

for(var i=0; i<vector.Length; i++)  
    vector[i] = set.Contains(universal[i]) ? 1 : 0;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", vector));
```

Вывод

```
1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0
```

Comment: Великолепно! Коротко - и по делу! Большое спасибо, tym32167!

Comment: Спасибо больше) Вы очень помогли мне

Comment: @S.H. вы меня снова перехваливаете :)

Comment: @Константин пожалуйста, хорошо, что разобрались